# Difficulty having Django find database user

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm writing a web app which has a page for admin tasks. One of the tasks is that the admin users must be able to edit other users details. Alas, I've fallen at quite a simple roadblock.

I've set up a very simple jQuery AJAX Get request, successfully transferring a string to the server and back. This is just background, but not the issue. The issue lies in retrieving other user's objects.

At the moment, with a username I know exists, this code which is accessed in views.py, produces a 500 Internal Server Error.

```
@login_required
def user_edit_getuser(request):
    # Like before, get the request's context.
    context = RequestContext(request)

    inputname = request.GET['inputNameSend']

    user_obj = User.objects.get(inputname)

    return HttpResponse(inputname) #later will return a JSON String
```

Comment: Please post the traceback/error that is displayed on the error page, thanks!

Comment: I don't know if it's because it's simply an AJAX request, but there was no error page shown in the browser. Frustratingly, all I can seem to see is the 500 Error in the console. Is there another place to look for more information on 500 errors?

Comment: During development, I recommend that you set TEMPLATE_DEBUG=True in settings.py. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#template-debug.

Comment: You can see the error in the Network tab of the web inspector of your choice. In the Chrome Development Tools, you can click on a request, select Preview or Response, and see the Django error page in a plain text format

Comment: A request is a request and every request you do from ajax can be done from any other client (your browser, curl, wget etc). So set DEBUG to true in your settings, point your browser to your view's URL and read the full traceback.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`get` takes keyword arguments only: the key is the field to look up.

```
user_obj = User.objects.get(username=inputname)
```

Also, you should probably deal with the possibility that the GET request has no `inputNameSend` key.

For JS development, you can usually see the error page in the Chrome dev tools/Firebug console in the Network tab.

Comment: Ah, that solved it, cheers! Relatively new to Python, but I assume I use the Try:Except: construct to check for usernames?

Comment: Either `try: ... except User.DoesNotExist`, or the get_object_or_404 sortcut, if you just want to 404 if the `User` does not exist